# Meaning of 落着き先?

Tags: meaning, translation, words, kanji

I'm a newish Japanese learner. I've been reading and translating short Japanese comics and videos to help familiarize myself with new kanji and word-play and whatnot.
However, I've been stuck for a few days trying to decipher the meaning of this specific sentence:

> お前の落着き先も
>
> 早く見つけてやらないとな

I can't quite figure out the meaning of 落着き先 here. I understand the second part is along the lines of "I have to see/find [it] soon." But the first part is what's confusing me the most.

I know the separate meanings of 落着き (落ち着き) and 先, but together I just can't understand it. I've tried searching multiple sites, reading multiple Japanese blogs/pages that use this word, and yet I just can't seem to make heads or tails of it.

For context, both lines are spoken by the same character. He says this to himself regarding a child he's taking care of. While both lines are separate textboxes, it's pretty obvious they connect.

Thank you in advance to anybody who reads this, it means a lot to me.

Comment: You've written "見っけて"; are you sure it isn't "見つけて"?

Comment: You're right! Flub on my part, sorry! It's 見つけて. ^^'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look up 落ち着き in a dictionary you can find definitions like "aplomb", "calm", "peacefulness" or "cool", but this is not how 落ち着き is used here. Here 落ち着き is simply the masu-stem of the verb 落ち着く, which can mean "to settle (down)" or "to finally end up".

- いろいろな議論があったが、リーダーは彼に落ち着いた。
  There was a lot of discussion, but it was settled that he was the leader.
- たくさん引っ越しをして、今は横浜に落ち着いています。
  I moved many times, and now I have settled in Yokohama.
- そろそろ落ち着いて[身を固め](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%BA%AB%E3%82%92%E5%9B%BA%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B)なさいよ。
  It's time for you to settle down and {marry someone / get a steady job}.

先 here is a suffix that refers to a (remote) place to which the preceding action is related. Look up 旅先, 連絡先 or 行き先. See: [Why is 先 needed in アルバイト先で?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25239/5010)

Therefore, this 落ち着き先 means "the place you settle in". The type of "place" depends on the context, but probably he is looking for the listener's next habitat and/or job.