# When I need to use 先 to mark a place?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

So I bump up in the following example and I struggle to understand the usage of 先. In this example, a boy meets his mother and he is angry about what she did.

```
勝手に俺の履歴書使ってパート先のスーパーに出しただろう
```

Form [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25239/why-is-%E5%85%88-needed-in-%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E5%85%88%E3%81%A7) I understood that it used to mark a place, but when do I need to use it? Isn't kind of obvious that we are talking about the supermarket workplace?

If I would say `勝手に俺の履歴書使ってパートのスーパーに出しただろう` it wouldn't be the same?

Thanks, Or.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the right question. 先 is a suffix that forms a noun that refers to a place. パート先 refers to one's workplace where they work part-time.

This の indicates パート先 and スーパー are in apposition, i.e., her workplace **is** the supermarket. See: [What's the difference between 日本人の学生 and 日本の学生 ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40892/5010)

Without 先, パートのスーパー doesn't make much sense because "part time job" is not a "supermarket" itself. Of course "part time job" cannot own a supermarket, either. In reality, パートのスーパー, バイトのピザ屋 and so on might be sometimes used if you're speaking very informally and there is enough context, but it's normally safer to add 先.

Comment: I think I start to understand. スーパーの`パート` won't make sense either?

Comment: @Smiled_One スーパーのパート refers to part-time workers of a supermarket :)